# Urwid: how to select the whole row, not one column?

Tags: python, urwid

Im coding around [this example](http://www.nicosphere.net/selectable-list-with-urwid-for-python-2542/) and I dont understand how to select the whole line when I press up or down arrows.

Comment: Link is broken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of `Columns` widget doesn't support multiple selection, you need to use your own container widget(it can be based on `Columns` with redefined `render` method), or just Text, for example this:

```
def __init__ (self, id, description):
    self.content = 'item %s: %s...' % (str(id), description[:25])
    self.item = urwid.AttrWrap(
        urwid.Text('item %s: %s' % (id, description)), 'body', 'focus'
        )
    super(ItemWidget, self).__init__(self.item)
```

works fine.
Also if your need in padding, your can emulate it with string formatting.

Comment: Спасибо:) Гугл грит что земляк и крестьянин это одно и то же:))

Comment: Hereafter in English, may be it will be helpful for someone else. Why are you using `ItemWidget` instead of `WidgetWrap` and `Columns`?

Comment: There is no real reason, `ItemWidget` is using in original example.

Comment: I did not noticed it... Also, how to place words with different foreground and background on the same line? I think it should be different `urwid.WidgetWrap` objects, but how to place them like this? And how to change style of `urwid.WidgetWrap` dynamically? I know about urwid.Text.set_text() but it is not what I need.

Comment: And yet it turns out that you're not use `urwid.Columns`... Why?